# java code design puzzle for common function result module

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a puzzle. I came up with a few classes to represent results. They looked similar, so I defined a common `Result` class. But what if I need to define different results according to different functions?

In other words, do I need `TypeOneResult` and `TypeTwoResult` or only `CommonResult`?

If I get rid of the different result classes and rely on `CommonResult`, how can I store some specific information about the result?

```
public class Result {
    private String id;
    private String data;

    public Result(String id, String data) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

---

```
class CommonResult extends Result{        
    private String type;

    public CommonResult(String id, String data, String type) {
        super(id, data);
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

---

```
class TypeOneResult extends CommonResult{

    public TypeOneResult(String id, String data, String type) {
        super(id, data, type);
    }
}
```

---

```
class TypeTwoResult extends CommonResult{

    public TypeTwoResult(String id, String data, String type) {
        super(id, data, type);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood your question fully, but from what I could understand, you do not need to have both TypeOneResult and TypeTwoResult.  In fact, you probably do not need either of them.  You can use the value of the `type` member of the CommonResult class to distinguish among the different types.